# jQuery Mobile for input style

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using jQuery Mobile the input fields all seem to be styled something like this

[image]

But most mobile apps, or iPhone at least, the fields tend to be styled as

[image]

How can I get jQuery Mobile to use the more standard style for inputs?

Answer (score 1):

There are some real trade offs between mobile web and native applications but the UI gets confusing when you start mixing the two.

jQuery Mobile renders a very similar web appearing interface across a number of mobile platforms and I believe that is one of its biggest strengths. The user sees web and experiences web like interactions.

Frameworks like telerik's [Kendo](http://www.kendoui.com/) render very native looking interfaces across iOS, Android and BlackBerry but they don't feel or interact in a native way which is confusing. Users see native but experience a web interactions.

If you really want native, consider other frameworks.